# Как выбрать словарь в котором есть элемент JSON + Python

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

```
[{'member_id': 1, 'invited_by': 1, 'is_admin': True, 'is_owner': True, 'join_date': 1680733383}, {'member_id': 2, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1680733383}, {'member_id': 3, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1682326770}]
```

У меня есть вот такой список, как мне вынести полный словарь в котором есть "'member_id': 3", допустим я хочу получить всю информацию у человеке с этим id и мне надо чтобы оно вывело:

```
{'member_id': 3, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1682326770}
```

И надо чтобы оно находило нужный словарь именно по id внутри, а не по индексу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно сделать генератор с условием и взять его первый элемент:

```py
>>> data = [{'member_id': 1, 'invited_by': 1, 'is_admin': True, 'is_owner': True, 'join_date': 1680733383}, {'member_id': 2, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1680733383}, {'member_id': 3, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1682326770}]
>>>
>>> [dict_ for dict_ in data if dict_['member_id'] == 3][0]
```

Выхлоп:

```py
{'member_id': 3, 'can_kick': True, 'invited_by': 1, 'join_date': 1682326770}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!